# Calling individual cell instead of range

Tags: excel, vba

The below macro is pulling a value from a cell which is referencing a range and then actioning accordingly. How can I change this to only run the case for the relevant entry in the cell?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case Phones4U, P4U
        Case MBNA, MBNA1
        'Case Is = O2, The_Problem_Network
        'Case Is = TMobile, TMobile
        'Case Is = 3, Run_3
        'Case Is = Orange, Orange
        'Case Is = Carphone_Warehouse, CPW
        'Case Is = Virgin_Media, VirginMedia
        'Case Is = Virgin_Mobile, VirginMobile
        'Case Is = Lifestyle_Group, LSG
        'Case Is = BT, BT
        'Case Is = Barclays, Barclays
        'Case Is = Nat_West, NatWest
        'Case Is = RBS, RBS
        'Case Is = Unipart, Unipart
        'Case Is = Vodafone_Group, Vodafone
    End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check whether the target cell C5 contains the text "MBNA", "Phones4U" etc? ... which your code isn't currently doing.

Comment: When the end user selects the company name from a drop down list e.g. MBNA I need the code above to run the relevant macro that is associated with that company name. Behind cell C5 is a drop down list of all the company names. So when the end user selects MBNA all of the macros run instead of the one associated with MBNA. How do I get the macros to only run for the selected company name in C5 and not all of the company names from the drop down list (range)?

Comment: How did you make the dropdown list (there are various ways of doing a dropdown list in Excel)

Comment: I typed out the list elsewhere on the spreadsheet then on cell C5 selected Data, Validation, allow list, then selected the range

Comment: is "P4U" just an alternative spelling of "Phones4U" that also shows on the list (and shares the same macro), or is it the name of the macro to run when "Phones4U" is selected? Likewise "MBNA" and "MBNA1", etc

Comment: P4U is the macro name as is MBNA1 etc etc

Comment: in that case, see the answer from gd047

Comment: You are welcome Steve! If an answer solves your question, then be sure to "accept" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a syntax like this should work without problems

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$C$5" Then
        Select Case Target.Value
        Case "Phones4U"
                P4U
        Case "MBNA"
                MBNA1
        Case "O2"
                The_Problem_Network
       ' etc
    End Select
    End If

End Sub
```